# INSERT long HTML code into mysql database (PDO, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I try to INSERT a html to database, problem is this whole html code is veeeery long sometimes and my table are to short even if i used LONGTEXT type of.

I tried use base64_encode, is eny other function to "archive" as text to get smaller query to INSERT to database and then "extract" to show him back in for example  using htmlspecialchart function ?

Comment: LONGTEXT can save upto 4GB, If you have html even longer than it, then you should store them in html files. You can write html in files and retrieve when needed using file functions

Comment: 4GB have not. Problem is this string of html is in "one line" so I think that is the problem of it. Is any way to save "&nbsp;" as " " normal space then mysql will know that this string is not so long, or mysql calculate whole charts inside table ?

Comment: When you try to save, does it throw some error like "string is truncated" etc?

Comment: No, mysql just cut a code and save with no errors to database.

Comment: try to escape string while saving.. e.g. addslashes($html)

Comment: still cut a code in the same name, but even if this will work that`s not resolved the problem, becouse i need this html tags to read some value from this code.

Comment: srry not name but place

Comment: can you paste your code for it with sample data, in your question. That may help to understand better

Comment: ok so, now is sometime insert source sometimes not. For sure is something with lenght of string,

Comment: Ok I see the error in database: " '\xE2\x9C\xAA Be.." string error in row 1